# New line in php

Tags: php

I have a function that generates all the permutation of a given numbers. The function is working fine but the output shows inline wihout break`<br>`I want to put a new line but `/n` is not working. What is wrong?

```
print(pc_permute(array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8))) . "\n";

function pc_permute($items, $perms = array( )) {
if (empty($items)) { 
    print join(' ', $perms) . "\n";
}  else {
    for ($i = count($items) - 1; $i >= 0; --$i) {
         $newitems = $items;
         $newperms = $perms;
         list($foo) = array_splice($newitems, $i, 1);
         array_unshift($newperms, $foo);
         pc_permute($newitems, $newperms);
     }
}
}
```

output:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 1 0 2 3 4 5 7 8 0 2 1 3 4 5 7 8 2 0 1 3 4 5 7 8 1 2 0 3 4 5 7 8 2 1 0 3 4 5 7 8 0 1 3 2 4 5 7 8 1 0 3 2 4 5 7 8 0 3 1 2 4 5 7 8 3 0 1 2 4 5 7 8 1 3 0 2 4 5 7 8 3 1 0 2 4 5 7 8 0 2 3 1 4 5 7 8 2 0 3 1 4 5 7 8 0 3 2 1 4 5 7 8 3 0 2 1 4 5 7 8 2 3 0 1 4 5 7 8 3 2 0 1 4 5 7 8 1 2 3 0 4 5 7 8 2 1 3 0 4 5 7 8 1 3 2 0 4 5 7 8 3 1 2 0 4 5 7 8 2 3 1 0 4 5 7 8 3 2 1 0 4 5 7 8 0 1 2 4 3 5 7 8 1 0 2 4 3 5 7 8 0 2 1 4 3 5 7 8 2 0 1 4 3 5 7 8 1 2 0 4 3 5 7 8 2 1 0 4 3 5 7 8 0 1 4 2 3 5 7 8 1 0 4 2 3 5 7 8 0 4 1 2 3 5 7 8 4 0 1 2 3 5 7 8 1 4 0 2 3 5 7 8 4 1 0 2 3 5 7 8 0 2 4 1 3 5 7 8 2 0 4 1 3 5 7 8 0 4 2 1 3 5 7 8 4 0 2 1 3 5 7 8 2 4 0 1 3 5 7 8 4 2 0 1 3 5 7 8 1 2 4 0 3 5 7 8 2 1 4 0 3 5 7 8 1 4 2 0 3 5 7 8 4 1 2 0 3 5 7 8 2 4 1 0 3 5 7 8 4 2 1 0 3 5 7 8 0 1 3 4 2 5 7 8 1 0 3 4 2 5 7 8 0 3 1 4 2 5 7 8 3 0 1 4 2 5 7 8 1 3 0 4 2 5 7 8 3 1 0 4 2 5 7 8 0 1 4 3 2 5 7 8 1 0 4 3 2 5 7 8 0 4 1 3 2 5 7 8 4 0 1 3 2 5 7 8 1 4 0 3 2 5 7 8 4 1 0 3 2 5 7 8 0 3 4 1 2 5 7 8 3 0 4 1 2 5 7 8 0 4 3 1 2 5 7 8 4 0 3 1 2 5 7 8 3 4 0 1 2 5 7 8 4 3 0 1 2 5 7 8 1 3 4 0 2 5 7 8 3 1 4 0 2 5 7 8 1 4 3 0 2 5 7 8 4 1 3 0 2 5 7 8 3 4 1 0 2 5 7 8 4 3 1 0 2 5 7 8 0 2 3 4 1 5 7 8 2 0 3 4 1 5 7 8 0 3 2 4 1 5 7 8 3 0 2 4 1 5 7 8 2 3 0 4 1 5 7 8 3 2 0 4 1 5 7 8 0 2 4 3 1 5 7 8 2 0 4 3 1 5 7 8 0 4 2 3 1 5 7 8 4 0 2 3 1 5 7 8 2 4 0 3 1 5 7 8 4 2 0 3 1 5 7 8 0 3 4 2 1 5 7 8 3 0 4 2 1 5 7 8 0 4 3 2 1 5 7 8 4 0 3 2 1 5 7 8 3 4 0 2 1 5 7 8 4 3 0 2 1 5 7 8 2 3 4 0 1 5 7 8 3 2 4 0 1 5 7 8 2 4 3 0 1 5 7 8 4 2 3 0 1 5 7 8 3 4 2 0 1 5 7 8 4 3 2 0 1 5 7 8 1 2 3 4 0 5 7 8 2 1 3 4 0 5 7 8 1 3 2 4 0 5 7 8 3 1 2 4 0 5 7 8 2 3 1 4 0 5 7 8 3 2 1 4 0 5 7 8 1 2 4 3 0 5 7 8 2 1 4 3 0 5 7 8 1 4 2 3 0 5 7 8 4 1 2 3 0 5 7 8 2 4 1 3 0 5 7 8 4 2 1 3 0 5 7 8 1 3 4 2 0 5 7 8 3 1 4 2 0 5 7 8 1 4 3 2 0 5 7 8 4 1 3 2 0 5 7 8 3 4 1 2 0 5 7 8 4 3 1 2 0 5 7 8 2 3 4 1 0 5 7 8 3 2 4 1 0 5 7 8 2 4 3 1 0 5 7 8 4 2 3 1 0 5 7 8 3 4 2 1 0 5 7 8 4 3 2 1 0 5 7 8 0 1 2 3 5 4 7 8 1 0 2 3 5 4 7 8 0 2 1 3 5 4 7 8 2 0 1 3 5 4 7 8 1 2 0 3 5 4 7 8 2 1 0 3 5 4 7 8 0 1 3 2 5 4 7 8 1 0 3 2 5 4 7 8 0 3 1 2 5 4 7 8 3 0 1 2 5 4 7 8 1 3 0 2 5 4 7 8 3 1 0 2 5 4 7 8 0 2 3 1 5 4 7 8 2 0 3 1 5 4 7 8 0 3 2 1 5 4 7 8 3 0 2 1 5 4 7 8 2 3 0 1 5 4 7 8 3 2 0 1 5 4 7 8 1 2 3 0 5 4 7 8 2 1 3 0 5 4 7 8 1 3 2 0 5 4 7 8 3 1 2 0 5 4 7 8 2 3 1 0 5 4 7 8 3 2 1 0 5 4 7 8 0 1 2 5 3 4 7 8 1 0 2 5 3 4 7 8 0 2 1 5 3 4 7 8 2 0 1 5 3 4 7 8 1 2 0 5 3 4 7 8 2 1 0 5 3 4 7 8 0 1 5 2 3 4 7 8 1 0 5 2 3 4 7 8 0 5 1 2 3 4 7 8 5 0 1 2 3 4 7 8 1 5 0 2 3 4 7 8 5 1 0 2 3 4 7 8 0 2 5 1 3 4 7 8 2 0 5 1 3 4 7 8 0 5 2 1 3 4 7 8 5 0 2 1 3 4 7 8 2 5 0 1 3 4 7 8 5 2 0 1 3 4 7 8 1 2 5 0 3 4 7 8 2 1 5 0 3 4 7 8 1 5 2 0 3 4 7 8 5 1 2 0 3 4 7 8 2 5 1 0 3 4 7 8 5 2 1 0 3 4 7 8 0 1 3 5 2 4 7 8 1 0 3 5 2 4 7 8 0 3 1 5 2 4 7 8 3 0 1 5 2 4 7 8 1 3 0 5 2 4 7 8 3 1 0 5 2 4 7 8 0 1 5 3 2 4 7 8 1 0 5 3 2 4 7 8 0 5 1 3 2 4 7 8 5 0 1 3 2 4 7 8 1 5 0 3 2 4 7 8 5 1 0 3 2 4 7 8 0 3 5 1 2 4 7 8 3 0 5 1 2 4 7 8 0 5 3 1 2 4 7 8 5 0 3 1 2 4 7 8 3 5 0 1 2 4 7 8 5 3 0 1 2 4 7 8 1 3 5 0 2 4 7 8 3 1 5 0 2 4 7 8 1 5 3 0 2 4 7 8 5 1 3 0 2 4 7 8 3 5 1 0 2 4 7 8 5 3 1 0 2 4 7 8 0 2 3 5 1 4 7 8 2 0 3 5 1 4 7 8 0 3 2 5 1 4 7 8 3 0 2 5 1 4 7 8 2 3 0 5 1 4 7 8 3 2 0 5 1 4 7 8 0 2 5 3 1 4 7 8 2 0 5 3 1 4 7 8 0 5 2 3 1 4 7 8 5 0 2 3 1 4 7 8 2 5 0 3 1 4 7 8 5 2 0 3 1 4 7 8 0 3 5 2 1 4 7 8 3 0 5 2 1 4 7 8 0 5 3 2 1 4 7 8 5 0 3 2 1 4 7 8 3 5 0 2 1 4 7 8 5 3 0 2 1 4 7 8 2 3 5 0 1 4 7 8 3 2 5 0 1 4 7 8 2 5 3 0 1 4 7 8 5 2 3 0 1 4 7 8 3 5 2 0 1 4 7 8 5 3 2 0 1 4 7 8 1 2 3 5 0 4 7 8 2 1 3 5 0 4 7 8 1 3 2 5 0 4 7 8 3 1 2 5 0 4 7 8 2 3 1 5 0 4 7 8 3 2 1 5 0 4 7 8 1 2 5 3 0 4 7 8 2 1 5 3 0 4 7 8 1 5 2 3 0 4 7 8 5 1 2 3 0 4 7 8 2 5 1 3 0 4 7 8 5 2 1 3 0 4 7 8 1 3 5 2 0 4 7 8 3 1 5 2 0 4 7 8 1 5 3 2 0 4 7 8 5 1 3 2 0 4 7 8 3 5 1 2 0 4 7 8 5 3 1 2 0 4 7 8 2 3 5 1 0 4 7 8 3 2 5 1 0 4 7 8 2 5 3 1 0 4 7 8 5 2 3 1 0 4 7 8 3 5 2 1 0 4 7 8 5 3 2 1 0 4 7 8 0 1 2 4 5 3 7 8 1 0 2 4 5 3 7 8 0 2 1 4 5 3 7 8 2 0 1 4 5 3 7 8 1 2 0 4 5 3 7 8 2 1 0 4 5 3 7 8 0 1 4 2 5 3 7 8 1 0 4 2 5 3 7 8 0 4 1 2 5 3 7 8 4 0 1 2 5 3 7 8 1 4 0 2 5 3 7 8 4 1 0 2 5 3 7 8 0 2 4 1 5 3 7 8 2 0 4 1 5 3 7 8 0 4 2 1 5 3 7 8 4 0 2 1 5 3 7 8 2 4 0 1 5 3 7 8 4 2 0 1 5 3 7 8 1 2 4 0 5 3 7 8 2 1 4 0 5 3 7 8 1 4 2 0 5 3 7 8 4 1 2 0 5 3 7 8 2 4 1 0 5 3 7 8 4 2 1 0 5 3 7 8 0 1 2 5 4 3 7 8 1 0 2 5 4 3 7 8 0 2 1 5 4 3 7 8 2 0 1 5 4 3 7 8 1 2 0 5 4 3 7 8 2 1 0 5 4 3 7 8 0 1 5 2 4 3 7 8 1 0 5 2 4 3 7 8 0 5 1 2 4 3 7 8 5 0 1 2 4 3 7 8 1 5 0 2 4 3 7 8 5 1 0 2 4 3 7 8 0 2 5 1 4 3 7 8 2 0 5 1 4 3 7 8 0 5 2 1 4 3 7 8 5 0 2 1 4 3 7 8 2 5 0 1 4 3 7 8 5 2 0 1 4 3 7 8 1 2 5 0 4 3 7 8 2 1 5 0 4 3 7 8 1 5 2 0 4 3 7 8 5 1 2 0 4 3 7 8 2 5 1 0 4 3 7 8 5 2 1 0 4 3 7 8 0 1 4 5 2 3 7 8 1 0 4 5 2 3 7 8 0 4 1 5 2 3 7 8 4 0 1 5 2 3 7 8 1 4 0 5 2 3 7 8 4 1 0 5 2 3 7 8 0 1 5 4 2 3 7 8 1 0 5 4 2 3 7 8 0 5 1 4 2 3 7 8 5 0 1 4 2 3 7 8 1 5 0 4 2 3 7 8 5 1 0 4 2 3 7 8 0 4 5 1 2 3 7 8 4 0 5 1 2 3 7 8 0 5 4 1 2 3 7 8 5 0 4 1 2 3 7 8 4 5 0 1 2 3 7 8 5 4 0 1 2 3 7 8 1 4 5 0 2 3 7 8 4 1 5 0 2 3 7 8 1 5 4 0 2 3 7 8 5 1 4 0 2 3 7 8 4 5 1 0 2 3 7 8 5 4 1 0 2 3 7 8 0 2 4 5 1 3 7 8 2 0 4 5 1 3 7 8 0 4 2 5 1 3 7 8 4 0 2 5 1 3 7 8 2 4 0 5 1 3 7 8 4 2 0 5 1 3 7 8 0 2 5 4 1 3 7 8 2 0 5 4 1 3 7 8 0 5 2 4 1 3 7 8 5 0 2 4 1 3 7 8 2 5 0 4 1 3 7 8 5 2 0 4 1 3 7 8 0 4 5 2 1 3 7 8 4 0 5 2 1 3 7 8 0 5 4 2 1 3 7 8 5 0 4 2 1 3 7 8 4 5 0 2 1 3 7 8 5 4 0 2 1 3 7 8 2 4 5 0 1 3 7 8 4 2 5 0 1 3 7 8 2 5 4 0 1 3 7 8 5 2 4 0 1 3 7 8 4 5 2 0 1 3 7 8 5 4 2 0 1 3 7 8 1 2 4 5 0 3 7 8 2 1 4 5 0 3 7 8 1 4 2 5 0 3 7 8 4 1 2 5 0 3 7 8 2 4 1 5 0 3 7 8 4 2 1 5 0 3 7 8 1 2 5 4 0 3 7 8 2 1 5 4 0 3 7 8 1 5 2 4 0 3 7 8 5 1 2 4 0 3 7 8 2 5 1 4 0 3 7 8 5 2 1 4 0 3 7 8 1 4 5 2 0 3 7 8 4 1 5 2 0 3 7 8 1 5 4 2 0 3 7 8 5 1 4 2 0 3 7 8 4 5 1 2 0 3 7 8 5 4 1 2 0 3 7 8 2 //and so on...
```

I want the otuput that looks like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 7 8
1 0 2 3 4 5 7 8
0 2 1 3 4 5 7 8
2 0 1 3 4 5 7 8
1 2 0 3 4 5 7 8
```

Comment: 1. It's `\n` and not `/n` 2. You either just use `<br>` or do: `nl2br("\n")`

Comment: Doesn't work. . I tried what u said.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://viper-7.com/iUFz6Y Are you looking at the html output or CLI?

Comment: Thanks in works now. . I changed the `\n` to `<br>` and it's works now.

Comment: That's what I said in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
print join(' ', $perms) . "<br>";
```